How to share a value type variable between threads by ref?
I want to share value type between 2 threads by ref.
Consider 2 classes - user and handler.
User constructs handler and tells it to change a variable after 1000ms that user references.
There could be many users with various flags. I can of course use an event or action or callback but wont it be a lot cleaner if I could pass flag by ref and simply change its value.
(NOTE - user does not need to know when exactly flag value changed! It only needs to have flag == true when user checks the flag at any arbitrary point of time after 1000ms)
I would write something like this (without using unsafe):
bool userFlag;
void UserInitHandler()
{
  var handler = new Handler(1000)
  handler.Start(ref userFlag);
}

class Handler
{
  ...
  void Start(ref bool flag)
  {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => 
    {
      Thread.Sleep(delay);
      flag = true;
    }      
  }
}


so it's not a variable but User._field?

No thats the whole point of what i am trying to avoid - i do NOT want handler to have any knowledge of user - it could be any class with any bool field/property or whatever.

An action delegate seem pretty clear: public void Start(Action<bool> signal) and handler.Start(x => userFlag = x);

A ref cannot be stored as a field (except for a very specific ref struct scenario, which doesn't apply here), and "captured variables" (i.e. the flag in the => {...}  lambda) require field storage. So: that isn't directly possible.
What is possible is that you share an object that has the bool as a field, and each thread individually accesses it by-ref from there. Additionally, note that when dealing with threading, you may need a memory-barrier or at least volatile access. Basically, then:
bool userFlag;
void UserInitHandler()
{
  var handler = new Handler(1000)
  handler.Start(this);
}
... // some check code
if (Volatile.Read(ref this.userFlag)) {...}

class Handler
{
  ...
  void Start(YourType owner) // the type with bool userFlag
  {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => 
    {
      Thread.Sleep(delay);
      Volatile.Write(ref owner.flag, true);
    }      
  }
}


An alternative, however, might be to use a pre-existing mechanism; for example a ManualResetEvent, AutoResetEvent, Semaphore, or a TaskCompletionSource (using the .Task's completion).

Additional note: using a thread-pool thread to Thread.Sleep is not an effective use of resources (pool threads, specifically). You might prefer to use Task.Delay, which again makes the Task option tempting. Consider:
public async Task Start()
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
}

and nothing else - you can then use the resulting Task from that to signal completion either synchronously (.Wait()) or asynchronously (await).

Re comment:


i do NOT want handler to have any knowledge of user - it could be any class with any bool field/property or whatever


Perhaps, then:
interface IHazFlag
{
    ref bool Flag { get; }
}

class YourType : IHazFlag
{
    private bool flag;
    ref bool IHazFlag.Flag => ref flag;
    // ...
}

and use IHazFlag in place of YourType. However, I wonder whether it makes more sense to shift the implementation details, so the consumer just needs to call Signal() (etc), and what that means is an implementation detail:
interface ICanSignal
{
    void Signal()
}
class YourType : ICanSignal
{
    private bool flag;
    void ICanSignal.Signal() => Volatile.Write(ref flag, true);
    // ...
}

